# Laravel Passport Oauth Customize page / auto redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Hi I would like to ask about laravel passport oauth confirmation page

[image]

This is the page when we are asked for authorization, I would like to customize this page, or even possible to skip this page to always authorize anyway since the requestor will be just an internal application

I tried to google this but no luck. Is that possible? if so please tell me how to, or any link will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Got the way to change the page
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#requesting-tokens

If possible to skip it, then it would be great

Comment: I wonder if extending /oauth/authorize controller is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the UI you can actually export the view and edit it
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#requesting-tokens

For the auto redirection, actually it can be done using laravel passport version ^7.30

Code:
https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1022

Documentation:
https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5226

But since I was using laravel version that dont support passport ^7.30, I need to create the override
reference:
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/243

What I did was, I copied this snippets
https://paste.laravel.io/6LN6q

Creating a new class extending the passport AuthorizationController and overriding the authorize function only